# Hibernate MapKeyColumn automatically persists?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have 2 entities `User` & `Vehicle` with a One to Many relationship through a JoinTable map & a list. If I have a persisted `User` in the database & I add a transient `Vehicle` to both the list on the user (user.vehicles) & the map on the user (user.activeVehicles), it somehow triggers a persist that will throw an error as soon as the transaction closes. Ex:

```
User user = new User();
user.save();
(commit, flush, & close transaction)

Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
user.vehicles.add(v);
user.activeVehicles.put("car", vehicle);


Address address = new Address();
address.save();
```

This transaction will throw an error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Vehicle`

Here are the 2 entities

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "hstoredatestring", typeClass = HstoreUserType.DateString.class)
})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
public class User extends Model
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Vehicle.class, mappedBy = "user")
    @Valid
    @Expose
    @OrderBy("id desc")
    public List<Vehicle> vehicles = Lists.newArrayList();

    @Expose
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_active_vehicle_map",
                joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id")
                    },
                inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
                })
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "dtype")
    public Map<String, Vehicle> activeVehicles = new HashMap<String, Vehicle>();
}
```

**Vehicle**

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "pumps")
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonUserType.class)
})
abstract public class Vehicle extends Model
{

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = User.class)
    public User user;
}
```

Comment: You might have to call v.save().  Alternately, you might try using @ElementCollection, but that might not be compatible with your Model base class.

Comment: Yes if I call `vehicle.save()` it will work fine. However, I don't even want to persists the `User` object or the `Vehicle` object, all I want to do is save the `Address` object, but I can't because hibernate marks the `Vehicle` object to be persisted

Comment: When you call user.save(), how are you obtaining the EntityManager context?  If it is reused in the address.save(); call, the User will still be contained and managed within it.  All changes to managed entities are picked up when flush or commit are called.  If this is the case, you can to get a new EntityManager context, detach the User instance from it, or just call clear after flush in the user.save() method.

Comment: It's a completely brand new `EntityManager`